# How to create Build Task for C#10 / .NET 6.0 project in Azure DevOps Server 2020

Tags: azure-pipelines, .net-6.0, azure-devops-server-2020, c#-10.0

I already have a build pipeline for an existing project. I tried to change to project to `<LangVersion>10</LangVersion>`. Now the build pipeline fails, because it says, 10 is not allowed.

I already installed **Build Tools 2022**, but it still didn't work. When I open the pipeline to change the **MSBuild** or **Visual Studio** version to be used in the build task, I can only select versions up to **2019** or **latest** (I picked latest here).

The **Build Tools 2019** are still installed (I don't wanted to risk, other pipelines to fail because of the update). So maybe the Build agent just takes the wrong MSBuild version? Maybe I have to update the Build Agent itself? (It doesn't work automatically, because of our company firewall, I would have to copy the newer version to the server for deployment.)

Can anyone tell me, what the official way is, to get this to work. My google search didn't give me usable results.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980204/how-do-i-update-my-azure-devops-on-premise-pipeline-tasks-to-include-msbuild-v17

Comment: I can't build the tasks (probably my company firewall). Any chance to download the tasks without having access to an cloud-hosted Azure-Devops?

Comment: Safest bet is to download them straight from any azure DevOps organization, can even be a temporary one created under a personal account). I could offer zip files, nut can't guarantee the contents of those zips. I wouldn't trust that personally. You either need to build the tasks (possibly on one of your own build servers?), Or download them.

Comment: In case you do trust my scripting capabilities, here is a repo that automatically downloads the latest snapshots of all tasks. There is a verbatim release as well as one that patches each task so it can be installed side-by-side (sxs) of the original task. https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tasks-zips/releases

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update my Azure DevOps on-premise Pipeline tasks to include MSBuild v17 and Visual Studio 2022?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980204/how-do-i-update-my-azure-devops-on-premise-pipeline-tasks-to-include-msbuild-v17)

Answer (score 0):

You should read on Mircosoft's devblog arcticle [MSBuild and 64-bit Visual Studio 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/msbuild-and-64-bit-visual-studio-2022/)

and check on [github example](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-msbuild)

Comment: If I understand that correctly, I must change all yaml files for this to work? That doesn't sound right! Are you sure, there is no clean way to do that?

Comment: Also, hasn#t worked. - For completeness: I change version to 17 and msbuildArchitecture to x64. But Agent still didn't found the msbuild verison.