# Visual Studio 2022 not showing up in the dropdown

Tags: visual-studio-2022, azure-devops-server-2020

We have on-prem Azure DevOps 2020 installed. We built a .net core 6 app in Visual Studio 2022.
However, when creating the build pipeline, VS 2022 is not showing up in the dropdown.

Has anyone faced this problem? Is MSFT supposed to release a patch that will start displaying VS 2022 in the dropdown?

[image]

Comment: check this: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72589873/5797900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people are running into this. No word from MS yet on when or if an update will be available. But these articles may help you find a workaround:

- [How do I update my Azure DevOps on-premise Pipeline tasks to include MSBuild v17 and Visual Studio 2022?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980204/how-do-i-update-my-azure-devops-on-premise-pipeline-tasks-to-include-msbuild-v17)
- https://jessehouwing.net/adding-visual-studio-2022-to-azure-devops-server-2020/
- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3662

FWIW, I'm working around it by using an explicit MSBuild path as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70876611/1882616). I added a `PreferredMSBuildExePath` variable to my pipeline and set it equal to `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe`. Then I made all my MSBuild steps use `$(PreferredMSBuildExePath)` as their MSBuild path under Specify Location. I also converted all my Visual Studio steps to MSBuild steps so I could use this explicit path variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would have been just easy if Microsoft would have included it as part of a patch instead of customers coming with workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for the mention. So far more than 275 organizations have started using my extension on the marketplace. Support for Visual Studio 2022 is officially expected with Azure DevOps Server 2022. I've not heard of an upcoming patch for 2020 or 2019 to officially add support.